# php.ini syntax error don't update anymore

Tags: php, apache

I updated my php.ini file to add an extension, but wrote two "=" instead of one:

```
  extension**==**pdo_mysql.so
```

I then typed:

```
service apache2 reload
```

So obviously I got an error message telling me that I have a syntax error.

I edited again the code and removed the line beginning with "extension".
The problem is that now, everytime I type again service apache2 reload, I keep getting the syntax error. Like if the file doesn't update anymore...

I'm scared to type "service apache2 **restart**" because I don't want to crash my installation...
Does anyone have an idea why it's not updating anymore? Is it safe to proceed with the restart command?

PS: It's the **same file than before**, **I have the permissions to edit it**, it's the **same path** than on the phpinfo() and the date shows **it updated**.

Thank you.

Comment: Often times when loading or unloading a module from apache, a restart may be required.  If you made the correct edit to the `php.ini`, I don't see a harm in restarting.  If it fails it will give you more information to help you track down the issue.  You can't just leave it be and hope it never restards.  :)

Comment: Thank you for the additional precisions @bc2946088. I already crashed my installation by playing too much with apache, didn't want to take the risk this time haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
service apache2 restart
```

then

```
service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Why should they `reload` after the restart?

Comment: @bc2946088 good question, but with restart I still had the errors...I guess something crashed inside apache.

Comment: What does `reload` and `restart` doesn't do?